# C# WCF compression with NetTcpBinding in net4.5

Tags: c#, wcf, compression

due to the network bottle ,I need to compress the data and transfer between from server and client.
before I used netTcpBing ,Now i want to change to compress with gzip

```
 <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding" listenBacklog="200" maxConnections="200"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             openTimeout="00:00:10"
             sendTimeout="00:00:10">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

But the problem is that I do not know how to configure it  in app.config.
I try to find the answer and used the code as following, it seems wrong.

```
 <customBinding>
    <binding name="BinaryHttpBindingWithNoAuth" listenBacklog="200" maxConnections="200"
             openTimeout="00:00:10"
             sendTimeout="00:00:10"
      >
      <binaryMessageEncoding  compressionFormat ="GZip"/>
      <httpTransport />
      </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

now  I do not know how to conigure it.